# REACT: Use setState in a function called from another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, setstate

I'm starting in ReactJS and I'm doing a score system for my game in React.

I used a component called Score to manage it.

I did a score value in the state that can be incremented by `increment()`.

The problem is that I would like to use this function from my App component (it's an example, I created `incrementScore()` to show it).

However my `increment()` can't gain access to `this.setState()` when the function is called from another component.

Note that I created a button "Increment" inside `Score.js` which uses `increment()` and it's works perfectly.

Have you a solution or could you just give a clue? Thanks!

**App.js:**

```
import Score from './Score'

class App extends React.Component {

  incrementScore() {
    Score.prototype.increment()
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h1 id="title">Game</h1>
          <Score />
          <Canvas /> {/*Not important here, just for the game*/}
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

**Score.js:**

```
import React from 'react'

class Score extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      score: 0
    }
    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this)
  }

  increment() {
    this.setState({
      score: this.state.score + 1 //this.state.score + 1
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p id="score">Score: {this.state.score}</p>
        <button>Incrementer</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default
```

Comment: If you need to have the state in the parent component, then define the `increment` method there, and pass it down to the child component as a prop. There is good example of this in the official React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if my other component isn't parent of score ? If I want to access incrementScore() by an other js class ?

Comment: Usually all your components are descendants of a common "root" component, which is often called `App`, as here. So given any 2 components you can always find a common ancestor (usually below the level of `App` itself) which you can lift the state to.

Comment: Ok... so we never can mix components and non-components classes ? Even when we want to create objects which represents canvas drawings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Robin, just move your state to your parent `App` component, and let your `Score` component be a 'stateless' component. Also, make sure to pass the increment function down as a prop and use that within your button as an `onClick` function.

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      score: 0
    }
    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this)
  }

  increment() {
    this.setState({
      score: this.state.score + 1 //this.state.score + 1
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 id="title">Game</h1>
        <Score scoreCount={this.state.score} increment={this.increment}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
const Score = props =>
      <div>
        <p id="score">Score: {props.scoreCount}</p>
        <button onClick={props.increment}>Incrementer</button>
      </div>
```

See a live example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wq4kqqz0mw

Comment: how to achieve kind of same in react hooks?
"suppose a functional component(FC) which call a function to set-state which is outside the FC scope"